# How to select the submenu of the flyout using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I want to select the submenu of the flyout using selenium webdriver. 
Also how can I simulate on hover on menu items using selenium.

Please guide or provide some tutorial for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [actions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) class, something like this you need:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("id"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver); 
Actions hover = builder.moveToElement(element);
hover.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String New_select_Just_Landed = "//*[@id='nav1']/a"; 

    WebElement Ba = driver.findElement(By.xpath(New_select_Just_Landed));
    WebElement subBa = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav1']/section/ul/li/a"));

    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(Ba).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000); System.out.println("Mouse hoover succeed");
    action.moveToElement(subBa).perform();
    subBa.click();
    System.out.println("Click Just Landed! succeed");
    Thread.sleep(5000L);
```

Comment: You should explain what your code does and how it answers the question. SO exists not just to answer questions but to educate.